# Large performance difference when apparently unrelated code is changed

Tags: c++, performance, inline, compiler-optimization, icc

I have a strange issue.
I was coding a simple asynchronous optimization algorithm in C++, using the OpenMP library.
I wrote the code and it works well, without any bug.

Then I tried to evaluate the computation time of a certain section of the code.
On my system, that section takes about 12 seconds.

Then, I noticed that if I comment lines of the code totally not related to that section, the computation time of that section decreases a lot! It drops down to about 1 second.

I do not know how to provide you a simple code showing my issue.
The code that I attach below is my original code from which I removed all the sections that do not create the time-issue.
Unfortunately I can not remove other lines from the code because every line that I tried to remove, changes the execution time of the section I am interested in.

The section I am referring to is this one and it is toward the end of the code:

```
double gradientD_time = omp_get_wtime();
compute_function_gradient_D(gradient_D, DX, K, M, N);
double gradientD_total = (omp_get_wtime()- gradientD_time);
```

You may see that here I am evaluating the computation time of the compute_function_gradient_D() function. If I run this code, it takes about 12 seconds to be executed.
    If you remove lines from the code, the execution time of that section drops down to 1 second.
Example of lines you may try to remove:

```
    std::string str_1 = folder + "parameters.dat";
    std::string str_2 = folder + "times.dat";
    std::string str_3 = folder + "merits.dat";
    std::string str_4 = folder + "values.dat";
    std::string str_5 = folder + "lipx.dat";
    std::string str_6 = folder + "lipd.dat";
```

or

```
throw std::exception();
```

or

```
merits[iter] = max_br_init;
```

These are lines totally unrelated to the section for which I am computing the execution time...why the execution time changes if I remove one of these lines? What is it happening here?

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include "mkl.h"
 void compute_function_gradient_D(double *gradient_D, double *DX, int K, int M, int N) {
    for (int j = 0; j < K; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++){
            gradient_D[j*M+i] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                gradient_D[i+M*j] += DX[i+k*M];
        }   
    }
 }

  double compute_D_const(double *D, int M, int K){
    double L1norm_col = 0.0, err0=0, err1 = 0.0, tol=1e-6, normx = 0.0, normy= 0.0, nrm2= 0.0;
    int count = 0;  
    double *Dt_col = new double[K]();
    double *DDtb = new double[M]();
    double *Dtb = new double[K]();
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        Dt_col[0:K:1] = D[i:K:M];
        L1norm_col = cblas_dasum(K, Dt_col, 1);
        DDtb[i] = L1norm_col; 
    }
    nrm2 = cblas_dnrm2(M, DDtb, 1);
    cblas_dscal(M, 1.0/nrm2, DDtb, 1);    
    err1 = nrm2;
    while(std::abs(err1-err0)>tol*err1 && count<20){
        err0 = err1;
        cblas_dgemv(CblasColMajor, CblasTrans, M, K, 1.0, D, M, DDtb, 1 , 0.0, Dtb, 1);
        cblas_dgemv(CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, M, K, 1.0, D, M, Dtb, 1, 0.0, DDtb, 1);
        normx = cblas_dnrm2(M, DDtb, 1);
        normy = cblas_dnrm2(K, Dtb, 1);
        err1 = normx/normy;
        cblas_dscal(M, 1.0/normx, DDtb, 1);
        count++;        
        if(count>100) break;
    }
    err1*= err1;
    delete [] Dt_col; delete [] DDtb; delete [] Dtb;
    return err1;
 }

void compute_function_gradient_X(double *gradient_X, double *D, double *DX,     int over_X, int fe_X, int K, int M, int kn) {
    int current_index_X = 0, col = 0, row = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < (kn+over_X); i++){
        gradient_X[i] = 0.0;
        current_index_X = fe_X + i;
        col = std::floor(current_index_X/K);
        row = current_index_X - col*K;
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            gradient_X[i] +=  D[M*row+j]*DX[M*col+j];
    }   
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int max_time = 15000;
    int max_iter = 1;
    int time_flag = 0;
    int merit_flag = 0;
    int iter_flag = 0;
    int iter = 0;
    int core_count = 0;     
    double merit_limit = 1e-6;
    double tau_0 = 1;
    int number_of_threads = 1;
    int M = 0;
    int K = 0;
    int N = 0;
    double entry = 0.0;
    int kn = 0.0;
    int uneven_X = 0;
    int uneven_D = 0;
    int k = 0;
    double lambda = 1;
    double constr = 1;
    double warm_up = 10;
    std::string data = "../../data/param.dat";
    FILE *file = fopen(data.c_str(), "r");
    if (file == NULL) { 
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl; 
        throw std::exception(); 
    }
    fscanf(file, "%lf", &entry); M = entry; fscanf(file, "\n");     
    fscanf(file, "%lf", &entry); K = entry; fscanf(file, "\n");                                     
    fscanf(file, "%lf", &entry); N = entry; fscanf(file, "\n"); 
    fscanf(file, "%lf", &entry); lambda = entry; fscanf(file, "\n");
    fscanf(file, "%lf", &entry); constr = entry; fscanf(file, "\n");    
    fscanf(file, "%lf", &entry); warm_up = entry;
    fclose(file);
    double *X = new double[N*K]();    
    double *D = new double[M*K]();  
    double *S = new double[N*M]();  
    double *times = new double[max_iter+2*number_of_threads+1]();
    double *merits = new double[max_iter+2*number_of_threads+1]();
    double *values = new double[max_iter+2*number_of_threads+1]();
    double *Lip_X = new double[max_iter+2*number_of_threads+1]();
    double *Lip_D = new double[max_iter+2*number_of_threads+1]();
    int *actual_iteration_vector = new int[number_of_threads]();
    double f_value = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < M*N; i++)
        f_value += S[i]*S[i];
    double *nabla_X_init = new double[K*N]();
    double max_br_init = 0.0;
    double x_hat_init = 0.0, gradient_init = 0.0, parameter_init = 0.0, tauX_init = 0.0, LipD_init = 0.0;
    double m_value = 9999;
    int t_warm_up = warm_up*number_of_threads;
    LipD_init = compute_D_const(D, M, K);
    tauX_init = std::max(LipD_init, tau_0);
    cblas_dgemm(CblasColMajor, CblasTrans, CblasNoTrans, K, N, M, -1.0, D, M, S, M, 0.0, nabla_X_init, K);
    for (int i = 0; i < (K*N); i++){
        gradient_init = nabla_X_init[i];
        x_hat_init = X[i] - gradient_init/tauX_init;
        parameter_init = lambda/tauX_init;
        if (x_hat_init >= parameter_init) 
            x_hat_init -= parameter_init;
        else {
            if (x_hat_init <= -parameter_init) 
            x_hat_init += parameter_init; 
            else 
                 x_hat_init = 0.0; 
        }
        if(std::abs(x_hat_init-X[i]) >= max_br_init)
            max_br_init = std::abs(x_hat_init-X[i]);
    }
    double *D_col_init = new double[M]();
    double *D_hat_init = new double[M*K]();
    double *max_br = new double[number_of_threads]();
    std::fill(max_br, max_br+number_of_threads, -9999);
    D_hat_init[0:M*K:1] = D[0:M*K:1];
    double col_norm_init = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++){
        D_col_init[0:M:1] = D[(i*M):M:1];
        col_norm_init = cblas_dnrm2(M, D_col_init, 1);
        if(col_norm_init > constr)
            D_hat_init[(i*M):M:1] *= constr/col_norm_init;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (M*K); i++){
        if(std::abs(D_hat_init[i]-D[i]) >= max_br_init)
            max_br_init = std::abs(D_hat_init[i]-D[i]);
    }
    values[iter] = 0.5*f_value; 
    merits[iter] = max_br_init;
    times[iter] = 0.0;
    iter++;         
    kn = std::floor((K*N)/number_of_threads);
    uneven_X = (K*N % number_of_threads);       
    k = std::floor(K/number_of_threads);
    uneven_D = (K % number_of_threads); 
    delete [] nabla_X_init; delete [] D_col_init; delete [] D_hat_init;
    double total = omp_get_wtime();
    double init_time = omp_get_wtime() - total; 
    int thread_id = 0;
    thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
    int over_X = 0;
    int over_D = 0;
    if ((uneven_X != 0) && (thread_id == (number_of_threads-1)))
        over_X = uneven_X; 
    if ((uneven_D != 0) && (thread_id == (number_of_threads-1)))
        over_D = uneven_D;     
    double *gradient_X = new double[kn+over_X]();   
    double *delta_X = new double[kn+over_X]();
    double *delta_D = new double[(k+over_D)*M]();
    double *D_col = new double[M]();
    int fe_X = thread_id*kn;
    int fe_D = thread_id*k;         
    double end  = 0.0, LipX = 0.0, LipD = 0.0, tauX = 0.0, tauD = 0.0, X_hat = 0.0, col_norm = 0.0, max_br_local = 0.0;
    double *D_hat = new double[(k+over_D)*M]();
    double *times_local = new double[max_iter+1]();         
    double *merits_local = new double[max_iter+1](); 
    double *values_local = new double[max_iter+1]();            
    int current_index_X = 0, current_index_D = 0;
    int actual_iteration = 1;
    times_local[0] = times[0];
    merits_local[0] = merits[0];
    values_local[0] = values[0];
    actual_iteration_vector[thread_id] = 1;
    double start = omp_get_wtime(); 
    double gradientX_total = 0.0;               
    double *gradient_D = new double[(k+over_D)*M](); 
    double *DX = new double[M*N]();
    while (iter_flag == 0 && merit_flag == 0 && time_flag == 0){
        double gradientX_time = omp_get_wtime();
        compute_function_gradient_X(gradient_X, D, DX, over_X, fe_X, K, M, kn);
        gradientX_total += (omp_get_wtime()-gradientX_time);
        double gradientD_time = omp_get_wtime();
        compute_function_gradient_D(gradient_D, DX, K, M, N);
        double gradientD_total = (omp_get_wtime()- gradientD_time);
        printf("Gradient D total = %f \n", gradientD_total); 
        iter++;
        if ((omp_get_wtime() - total) >= max_time)
            time_flag = 1; 
        if (m_value <= merit_limit)
            merit_flag = 1; 
        if (iter >= max_iter)
            iter_flag = 1;
        }
        end = omp_get_wtime();
        #pragma omp barrier
        int value = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < thread_id; i++)
            value +=  (actual_iteration_vector[i]-1);
        for (int i = 0; i < (actual_iteration_vector[thread_id]-1); i++){
            times[value+1+i] = times_local[i+1];
            merits[value+1+i] = merits_local[i+1];
            values[value+1+i] = values_local[i+1];
        }    
        delete [] X; delete [] D; delete [] S; delete [] times; delete [] merits; delete [] values; delete [] Lip_X;
        delete [] Lip_D; delete [] actual_iteration_vector; delete [] max_br; delete [] gradient_D; delete [] DX;
        delete [] gradient_X; delete [] delta_X; delete [] delta_D; delete [] D_col; delete [] D_hat;
        delete [] times_local; delete [] merits_local; delete [] values_local;
        std::string folder = "../results/";
        std::string str_1 = folder + "parameters.dat";
        std::string str_2 = folder + "times.dat";
        std::string str_3 = folder + "merits.dat";
        std::string str_4 = folder + "values.dat";
        std::string str_5 = folder + "lipx.dat";
        std::string str_6 = folder + "lipd.dat";
        return 0;
}
```

It really does not matter the meaning of the code. Actually, since I removed many lines, the code does not have meaning anymore.
At the beginning a file called "param" has been read: it contains only six input values different from zeros:

```
64 
64
255025
0.125
1
1000000
```

In order to run the code I use the following cmake file:

```
project(example)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "icc")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_CXX_FLAGS)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-qopenmp -mkl=sequential")
add_executable(example main.cpp)
```

which, through the command `cmake` creates the makefile. Then I do `make` and finally I run the binary.

Comment: Could you provide a sample input file? Is the observed time consistent among multiple iterations? Use optimization flags (e.g. `-O3`) when discussing performance things. You never use `gradient_D`, the compiler could optimize away the whole thing entirely seemingly at random. Use `icpc` as `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` to ensure linking C++ libraries.

Comment: The input file is a .dat file containing:

`64
64
255025
0.125
1
1000000`.  Each number written in a different row.

Comment: Even with `icpc` or `-o3` it does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately I was able to reproduce the issue. There is a super helpful flag for the intel compiler, `-qopt-report=5`. This will create a file `main.optrpt` with all sorts of interesting things about compiler optimization, in particular for the *slow* version:

```
  -> (225,5) compute_function_gradient_D(double *, double *, int, int, int) (isz = 56) (sz = 69)
     [[ Inlining inhibited by overrideable criterion  <2>]]
```

The *fast* version is simply missing the second line.

Based on these:

```
INLINING OPTION VALUES:
  -inline-factor: 100
  -inline-min-size: 30
  -inline-max-size: 230
  -inline-max-total-size: 2000
  -inline-max-per-routine: 10000
  -inline-max-per-compile: 500000
```

I guess that the `criterion <2>` is `-inline-max-size`.
Indeed adding `-inline-max-size=999` speeds up the *slow* version of the code to the same level! So it was the **size of the `main` function** that was changed by the seemingly unrelated statements and **prevented inlining**.

You might still be wondering where the huge difference between inlining and not comes from. The function call itself is certainly not relevant. But let's look at the respective outputs:

For the function itself:

```
Begin optimization report for: compute_function_gradient_D(double *, double *, int, int, int)

    Report from: Interprocedural optimizations [ipo]

INLINE REPORT: (compute_function_gradient_D(double *, double *, int, int, int)) [10/60=16.7%] main.cpp(17,41)


    Report from: Loop nest, Vector & Auto-parallelization optimizations [loop, vec, par]


LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(18,3)
   remark #15344: loop was not vectorized: vector dependence prevents vectorization
   remark #15346: vector dependence: assumed FLOW dependence between gradient_D[j*M+i] (20:7) and DX[i+k*M] (22:9)
   remark #15346: vector dependence: assumed ANTI dependence between DX[i+k*M] (22:9) and gradient_D[j*M+i] (20:7)

   LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(19,5)
      remark #15344: loop was not vectorized: vector dependence prevents vectorization
      remark #15346: vector dependence: assumed FLOW dependence between gradient_D[j*M+i] (20:7) and DX[i+k*M] (22:9)
      remark #15346: vector dependence: assumed ANTI dependence between DX[i+k*M] (22:9) and gradient_D[j*M+i] (20:7)

      LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(21,7)
         remark #15344: loop was not vectorized: vector dependence prevents vectorization
         remark #15346: vector dependence: assumed FLOW dependence between gradient_D[i+M*j] (22:9) and gradient_D[i+M*j] (22:9)
         remark #15346: vector dependence: assumed ANTI dependence between gradient_D[i+M*j] (22:9) and gradient_D[i+M*j] (22:9)
         remark #25439: unrolled with remainder by 2  
      LOOP END

      LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(21,7)
      <Remainder>
      LOOP END
   LOOP END
LOOP END
```

The inlined version:

```
LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(18,3) inlined into main.cpp(225,5)
<Distributed chunk1>
   remark #25426: Loop Distributed (2 way) 
   remark #15542: loop was not vectorized: inner loop was already vectorized

   LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(19,5) inlined into main.cpp(225,5)
   <Distributed chunk1>
      remark #25426: Loop Distributed (2 way) 
      remark #25408: memset generated
      remark #15542: loop was not vectorized: inner loop was already vectorized

      LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(19,5) inlined into main.cpp(225,5)
      <Distributed chunk1>
         remark #15389: vectorization support: reference U55_V[j*M+i] has unaligned access   [ main.cpp(20,7) ]
         remark #15381: vectorization support: unaligned access used inside loop body
         remark #15305: vectorization support: vector length 2
         remark #15399: vectorization support: unroll factor set to 2
         remark #15309: vectorization support: normalized vectorization overhead 0.300
         remark #15301: PARTIAL LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
         remark #15451: unmasked unaligned unit stride stores: 1 
         remark #15475: --- begin vector cost summary ---
         remark #15476: scalar cost: 4 
         remark #15477: vector cost: 2.500 
         remark #15478: estimated potential speedup: 1.450 
         remark #15488: --- end vector cost summary ---
         remark #25015: Estimate of max trip count of loop=3
      LOOP END

      LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(19,5) inlined into main.cpp(225,5)
      <Remainder loop for vectorization, Distributed chunk1>
         remark #25015: Estimate of max trip count of loop=12
      LOOP END
   LOOP END
LOOP END

LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(18,3) inlined into main.cpp(225,5)
<Distributed chunk2>
   remark #25444: Loopnest Interchanged: ( 1 2 3 ) --> ( 1 3 2 )
   remark #15542: loop was not vectorized: inner loop was already vectorized

   LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(21,7) inlined into main.cpp(225,5)
   <Distributed chunk2>
      remark #15542: loop was not vectorized: inner loop was already vectorized

      LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(19,5) inlined into main.cpp(225,5)
      <Peeled loop for vectorization>
         remark #25015: Estimate of max trip count of loop=1
      LOOP END

      LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(19,5) inlined into main.cpp(225,5)
         remark #15388: vectorization support: reference U55_V[i+M*j] has aligned access   [ main.cpp(22,9) ]
         remark #15388: vectorization support: reference U55_V[i+M*j] has aligned access   [ main.cpp(22,9) ]
         remark #15388: vectorization support: reference U58_V[i+k*M] has aligned access   [ main.cpp(22,34) ]
         remark #15305: vectorization support: vector length 2
         remark #15399: vectorization support: unroll factor set to 4
         remark #15309: vectorization support: normalized vectorization overhead 0.700
         remark #15301: PERMUTED LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
         remark #15442: entire loop may be executed in remainder
         remark #15448: unmasked aligned unit stride loads: 2 
         remark #15449: unmasked aligned unit stride stores: 1 
         remark #15475: --- begin vector cost summary ---
         remark #15476: scalar cost: 8 
         remark #15477: vector cost: 2.500 
         remark #15478: estimated potential speedup: 3.050 
         remark #15488: --- end vector cost summary ---
      LOOP END

      LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(19,5) inlined into main.cpp(225,5)
      <Alternate Alignment Vectorized Loop>
      LOOP END

      LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(19,5) inlined into main.cpp(225,5)
      <Remainder loop for vectorization>
         remark #15388: vectorization support: reference U55_V[i+M*j] has aligned access   [ main.cpp(22,9) ]
         remark #15388: vectorization support: reference U55_V[i+M*j] has aligned access   [ main.cpp(22,9) ]
         remark #15389: vectorization support: reference U58_V[i+k*M] has unaligned access   [ main.cpp(22,34) ]
         remark #15381: vectorization support: unaligned access used inside loop body
         remark #15335: remainder loop was not vectorized: vectorization possible but seems inefficient. Use vector always directive or -vec-threshold0 to override 
         remark #15305: vectorization support: vector length 2
         remark #15309: vectorization support: normalized vectorization overhead 1.083
      LOOP END
   LOOP END
LOOP END
```

In the inlined version, the compiler knows more things about parameters, whereas the function itself needs to work for general parameters. However, the report discloses a general optimization. That is splitting the loop in two parts and changing the loop order for the second into a more optimized version that goes through memory linearly. This can also be applied to the C code itself:

```
void compute_function_gradient_D(double *gradient_D, double *DX, int K, int M,
                                 int N) {
  for (int j = 0; j < K; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
      gradient_D[j * M + i] = 0;
    }
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < K; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        gradient_D[i + M * j] += DX[i + k * M];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this code, the compiler also vectorizes the second loop for similar performance, even when the function is not inlined.

As you can see, the whole thing has nothing to do with OpenMP whatsoever.

<sup>All results with icpc 17.0.1, `-fopenmp -mkl=sequential -Wall -g -O3`</sup>

Comment: Amazing, thank you.
Just a couple of questions: why the default value for `-inline-max-size` is so low? In this example that value created an issue to me, isn't it more reasonable a bigger default value?
How can I change that value in my future works? Should I add the flag `-inline-max-size=999` in every cmake?

Comment: Inlining is also a tradeoff, the disadvange is huge (binary) code, which can hurt instruction cache usage. I think this is quite a corner case, and I wouldn't worry too much. In your case I would apply the transformation on the C code and not worry about it anymore. For all further performance optimization, resort to performance analysis first.